# Get the document with the max value of a field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm using aggregation framework to get the max value of a field from a collection across a set of documents, like this

```
db.getCollection('Collection').aggregate([
   {$match: {"product": {$in: ["product-a"]}}},
   {$group: {_id: null, maxPrice: {$max: "$price"}}}
])
```

But what if I want to get the ID of the document that matches this criteria? How can I do that in the next stage of the pipeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put all the fields in [**`$max`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) operator like this... It will give you the document for the max field which is used at first in the [**`$max`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/)  object. Just I have used `price` here.

```
db.getCollection("Collection").aggregate([
  { "$match": { "product": { "$in": ["product-a"] } } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "maxPrice": {
      "$max": {
        "price": "$price",
        "_id": "$_id"
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know why I didn't thought you can project multiple fields in $max operator

Comment: Will it pick the document with the greatest `_id` in case `price` values are equal?

Comment: @GregoryPakosz then you should put `_id` first.

Comment: If I put `_id` first, then it will pick the document with the greatest `_id` right? What I was wondering is: is `_id` used at all in the comparison. I would say yes, and wanted to confirm is price is the same for two documents, then the document with the greater `_id` wins